# Awk find and replace

Tags: bash, awk

I have edited question.
I have xml file (FILE1) that looks like:

```
<Sector sectorNumber="1">
        <Cell cellNumber="1" cellCreated="YES" cellIdentity="" cellRange="35000" numberOfTxBranches="1" hsCodeResourceId="0"/>
        <Cell cellNumber="2" cellCreated="YES" cellIdentity="" cellRange="35000" numberOfTxBranches="1" hsCodeResourceId="0"/>
        <Cell cellNumber="3" cellCreated="YES" cellIdentity="" cellRange="35000" numberOfTxBranches="1" hsCodeResourceId="0"/>
      </Sector>
      <Sector sectorNumber="2">
        <Cell cellNumber="1" cellCreated="YES" cellIdentity="" cellRange="35000" numberOfTxBranches="1" hsCodeResourceId="0"/>
        <Cell cellNumber="2" cellCreated="YES" cellIdentity="" cellRange="35000" numberOfTxBranches="1" hsCodeResourceId="0"/>
        <Cell cellNumber="3" cellCreated="YES" cellIdentity="" cellRange="35000" numberOfTxBranches="1" hsCodeResourceId="0"/>
      </Sector>
      <Sector sectorNumber="3">
        <Cell cellNumber="1" cellCreated="YES" cellIdentity="" cellRange="35000" numberOfTxBranches="1" hsCodeResourceId="0"/>
        <Cell cellNumber="2" cellCreated="YES" cellIdentity="" cellRange="35000" numberOfTxBranches="1" hsCodeResourceId="0"/>
        <Cell cellNumber="3" cellCreated="YES" cellIdentity="" cellRange="35000" numberOfTxBranches="1" hsCodeResourceId="0"/>
      </Sector>
```

and I have another file (FILE2) with input data for this xml file:

```
Cell11="42921"
Cell12="42925"
Cell13="42928"
Cell21="42922"
Cell22="42926"
Cell23="42929"
Cell31="42923"
Cell32="42927"
Cell33="42920"
```

What i want to do is, assign to all `cellIdentity=""` values from FILE2, in order. So it should look like this:

```
<Sector sectorNumber="1">
        <Cell cellNumber="1" cellCreated="YES" cellIdentity="42921" cellRange="35000" numberOfTxBranches="1" hsCodeResourceId="0"/>
        <Cell cellNumber="2" cellCreated="YES" cellIdentity="42925" cellRange="35000" numberOfTxBranches="1" hsCodeResourceId="0"/>
        <Cell cellNumber="3" cellCreated="YES" cellIdentity="42928" cellRange="35000" numberOfTxBranches="1" hsCodeResourceId="0"/>
      </Sector>
      <Sector sectorNumber="2">
        <Cell cellNumber="1" cellCreated="YES" cellIdentity="42922" cellRange="35000" numberOfTxBranches="1" hsCodeResourceId="0"/>
        <Cell cellNumber="2" cellCreated="YES" cellIdentity="42926" cellRange="35000" numberOfTxBranches="1" hsCodeResourceId="0"/>
        <Cell cellNumber="3" cellCreated="YES" cellIdentity="42929" cellRange="35000" numberOfTxBranches="1" hsCodeResourceId="0"/>
      </Sector>
      <Sector sectorNumber="3">
        <Cell cellNumber="1" cellCreated="YES" cellIdentity="42923" cellRange="35000" numberOfTxBranches="1" hsCodeResourceId="0"/>
        <Cell cellNumber="2" cellCreated="YES" cellIdentity="42927" cellRange="35000" numberOfTxBranches="1" hsCodeResourceId="0"/>
        <Cell cellNumber="3" cellCreated="YES" cellIdentity="42920" cellRange="35000" numberOfTxBranches="1" hsCodeResourceId="0"/>
      </Sector>
```

I used the code:

```
 awk 'NR==FNR{FS="=";a[NR]=$2;next}/cell/{c++;FS=OFS;$4="cellIdentity="a[c];}1' FILE2 FILE1
```

but I get this:

```
<Sector sectorNumber="1"> 
        <Cell cellNumber "1" cellCreated "YES" cellIdentity cellIdentity= "35000" numberOfTxBranches "1"  hsCodeResourceId "0" />
<Cell cellNumber="2" cellCreated="YES" cellIdentity="42925" cellRange="35000" numberOfTxBranches="1" hsCodeResourceId="0" />
<Cell cellNumber="3" cellCreated="YES" cellIdentity="42928" cellRange="35000" numberOfTxBranches="1" hsCodeResourceId="0" />
</Sector>

<Sector sectorNumber="2"> 
<Cell cellNumber="1" cellCreated="YES" cellIdentity="42922" cellRange="35000" numberOfTxBranches="1" hsCodeResourceId="0" />  
<Cell cellNumber="2" cellCreated="YES" cellIdentity="42926" cellRange="35000" numberOfTxBranches="1" hsCodeResourceId="0" />
<Cell cellNumber="3" cellCreated="YES" cellIdentity="42929" cellRange="35000" numberOfTxBranches="1" hsCodeResourceId="0" />
</Sector>

<Sector sectorNumber="3">   
<Cell cellNumber="1" cellCreated="YES" cellIdentity="42923" cellRange="35000" numberOfTxBranches="1" hsCodeResourceId="0" />
<Cell cellNumber="2" cellCreated="YES" cellIdentity="42927" cellRange="35000" numberOfTxBranches="1" hsCodeResourceId="0" />
<Cell cellNumber="3" cellCreated="YES" cellIdentity="42920" cellRange="35000" numberOfTxBranches="1" hsCodeResourceId="0" />
</Sector>
```

so as you can see I have problme with Cellidentitny in first line

```
<Cell cellNumber "1" cellCreated "YES" cellIdentity cellIdentity= "35000" numberOfTxBranches "1"  hsCodeResourceId "0" />
```

it desn't not set the first line, and all other lines are ok, and I don't know why.

Comment: Don't say `/cellIdentity/{$(NF-1)=a[++i]}` - instead say `/cellIdentity/{$(NF-7)=a[++i]}`

Comment: Adjust the indentation of all the lines in the input file and then you should get the result.

Comment: I use xmllint --format FILE1 to format file, so indetation is removed. Strange is why does remove all "=" from first row as i mentioned above...I use ubuntu 12 is it means something

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
awk 'FNR==NR
     {FS="=";a[NR]=$2;next}
     /cell/{c++;FS=OFS;
            $4="cellIdentity="a[c];}1' file2 file1
```

Tested Below:

```
> cat file1
<Sector sectorNumber="1">
<Cell cellNumber="1" cellCreated="YES" cellIdentity="" cellRange="35000" numberOfTxBranches="1" hsCodeResourceId="0"/>
<Cell cellNumber="2" cellCreated="YES" cellIdentity="" cellRange="35000" numberOfTxBranches="1" hsCodeResourceId="0"/>
<Cell cellNumber="3" cellCreated="YES" cellIdentity="" cellRange="35000" numberOfTxBranches="1" hsCodeResourceId="0"/>
</Sector>
<Sector sectorNumber="2">
<Cell cellNumber="1" cellCreated="YES" cellIdentity="" cellRange="35000" numberOfTxBranches="1" hsCodeResourceId="0"/>
<Cell cellNumber="2" cellCreated="YES" cellIdentity="" cellRange="35000" numberOfTxBranches="1" hsCodeResourceId="0"/>
<Cell cellNumber="3" cellCreated="YES" cellIdentity="" cellRange="35000" numberOfTxBranches="1" hsCodeResourceId="0"/>
</Sector>
<Sector sectorNumber="3">
<Cell cellNumber="1" cellCreated="YES" cellIdentity="" cellRange="35000" numberOfTxBranches="1" hsCodeResourceId="0"/>
<Cell cellNumber="2" cellCreated="YES" cellIdentity="" cellRange="35000" numberOfTxBranches="1" hsCodeResourceId="0"/>
<Cell cellNumber="3" cellCreated="YES" cellIdentity="" cellRange="35000" numberOfTxBranches="1" hsCodeResourceId="0"/>
</Sector>
> cat file2
Cell11="42921"
Cell12="42925"
Cell13="42928"
Cell21="42922"
Cell22="42926"
Cell23="42929"
Cell31="42923"
Cell32="42927"
Cell33="42920"
> awk 'FNR==NR{FS="=";a[NR]=$2;next}/cell/{c++;FS=OFS;$4="cellIdentity="a[c];}1' file2 file1
<Sector sectorNumber="1">
<Cell cellNumber="1" cellCreated="YES" cellIdentity="42921" cellRange="35000" numberOfTxBranches="1" hsCodeResourceId="0"/>
<Cell cellNumber="2" cellCreated="YES" cellIdentity="42925" cellRange="35000" numberOfTxBranches="1" hsCodeResourceId="0"/>
<Cell cellNumber="3" cellCreated="YES" cellIdentity="42928" cellRange="35000" numberOfTxBranches="1" hsCodeResourceId="0"/>
</Sector>
<Sector sectorNumber="2">
<Cell cellNumber="1" cellCreated="YES" cellIdentity="42922" cellRange="35000" numberOfTxBranches="1" hsCodeResourceId="0"/>
<Cell cellNumber="2" cellCreated="YES" cellIdentity="42926" cellRange="35000" numberOfTxBranches="1" hsCodeResourceId="0"/>
<Cell cellNumber="3" cellCreated="YES" cellIdentity="42929" cellRange="35000" numberOfTxBranches="1" hsCodeResourceId="0"/>
</Sector>
<Sector sectorNumber="3">
<Cell cellNumber="1" cellCreated="YES" cellIdentity="42923" cellRange="35000" numberOfTxBranches="1" hsCodeResourceId="0"/>
<Cell cellNumber="2" cellCreated="YES" cellIdentity="42927" cellRange="35000" numberOfTxBranches="1" hsCodeResourceId="0"/>
<Cell cellNumber="3" cellCreated="YES" cellIdentity="42920" cellRange="35000" numberOfTxBranches="1" hsCodeResourceId="0"/>
</Sector>
>
```

Comment: it's working, except first row, value cellIdentity="42921" it does not set..I get this cellIdentity cellIdentity=

Answer (score 1):

I suggest to do this with a programming language that has XML support instead of awk and bash script.

For example, Python. The code might be a tiny bit longer, but in exchange it won't break your XML file as easily.

So if you want to assign the IDs line-wise, in the order they appear in the text file:

```
import re
from xml.dom import minidom
from itertools import izip

sector_doc = minidom.parse('sectors.xml')
cells = sector_doc.getElementsByTagName('Cell')

with open('cells.txt', 'r') as cell_file:
    lines = cell_file.readlines()

for line, cell in izip(lines, cells):
    m = re.search('Cell\d+="([^"]+)"', line)
    if m: cell.setAttribute('cellIdentity', m.group(1))

with open('sectors_out.xml', 'wb') as out_file:
    sector_doc.writexml(out_file)
```